# Change default CSS classes

Tags: css, r, knitr

I would like to post knitr formatted code to my blog though the default CSS classes `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, `h6`. But overriding the CSS classes on Blogger causes problems.

How do I change the default CSS classes to be say `hh1`, `hh2`, ...?

This change would preferably be able to be used within RStudio's “Knit HTML” structure.

Answer (score 1):

Could you scope the inserted content inside a wrapper?
If yes, than you could create a selector based on that wrapper, something like:

```css
.wrapper h1 {
 //some style
}

.wrapper h2 {
 //some style
}
```